# CSS making an element that normally floats right, go to a new line when viewport is too small

Tags: html, css

I have 2 elements in a container that properly sticks to left and right edges:

https://jsfiddle.net/jamesjsfiddle/n3ta0Lro/1/

Html:

```
<div class="subsectionTitle">
  <div class="subsectionTitle__title">This is my title! It could potentially be very long.</div>
  <div class="subsectionTitle__date">Start date and end date</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.subsectionTitle{
    font-weight: 700;
    position: relative;
}

.subsectionTitle__title{
    display: inline-block
}

.subsectionTitle__date{
    float: right;

}
```

[image]

But when the viewport becomes too small, output looks like this instead:

[image]

I am trying to get it to look like this when the viewport is too small:
[image]

What's a smart change I can make to achieve this? Javascript is okay too.

Comment: Use media queries to make it responsive, you specify the break points. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by applying a `display: flex` property, `flex-wrap: wrap` and `justify-content: space-bewtween` to the parent. No need to set a media query! ;)

```css
.subsectionTitle{
    font-weight: 700;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="subsectionTitle">
  <div class="subsectionTitle__title">This is my title! It could be very long.</div>
  <div class="subsectionTitle__date">December 2020 - July 2020</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a media query for a max-width => `@media (max-width: 480px){ }`

```css
.subsectionTitle {
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
}

.subsectionTitle__title {
  display: inline-block
}

.subsectionTitle__date {
  float: right;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .subsectionTitle__date {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="subsectionTitle">
  <div class="subsectionTitle__title">This is my title! It could be very long.</div>
  <div class="subsectionTitle__date">December 2020 - July 2020</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Uses the @media rule to include a block of CSS properties only if a certain condition is true. add a breakpoint where certain parts of the design will behave differently on each side of the breakpoint.

```
.subsectionTitle{
    font-weight: 700;
    position: relative;
}

.subsectionTitle__title{
    display: inline-block
}

.subsectionTitle__date{
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .subsectionTitle__date {
    float: none;
  }
}
```